# Primefaces Autocomplete returning list is based on the values of other fields. How do I do?

Tags: ajax, autocomplete, primefaces

Pictures speak better than words...
[image]

I want to return the street address but for that I have to pass city and state. I've tried many ways and I could not, because I'm not understanding but I think when I make an ajax autocomplete and set the values ​of city and state, the values don't are going through to the managedbeans. They pass only when I advance in wizard, perhaps because the autocomplete process and just update itself (even me trying to update the other fields through other ajax requests within autocomplete tags).

The following code:

```
<p:autoComplete global="true" id="autoCompleteEnderecoCidadesLogradouro" 
 completeMethod="#{cidadeMB.autoCompletaEnderecoPojo}" 
 value="#{cidadeMB.enderecoTemp}" var="e" itemValue="#{e}"
 itemLabel="#{cidadeMB.cidade.endereco.logradouro}" converter="enderecoConverter"
 forceSelection="true" minQueryLength="5" maxResults="15" queryDelay="800"
 styleClass="textoLogradouro">
  <p:ajax process=":tabViewSistema:tabViewCadastro:formAddCidades:testeCidadeInput"
   update=":tabViewSistema:tabViewCadastro:formAddCidades:testeCidadeInput"/>
    <p:column>#{e.logradouro}</p:column>
    <p:column>#{e.cep}</p:column>
    <p:column>#{e.uf}</p:column>

  <p:ajax event="itemSelect" listener="#{cidadeMB.handleSelecaoDeEndereco}"
   update=":tabViewSistema:tabViewCadastro:formAddCidades:panelAddCidadesT3"/>  
</p:autoComplete>
```

Can anyone give me a hint how to do it?

Comment: Your explanations in your image should be in english too! And I think not enough code is shown. If you want to update the autocomplete datasource via ajax from a other component you have to call a bean method in your ajax call and update the datasource values according to that value and maybe other params?

Comment: I've managed to solve this issue. I wanted to pass the managed bean to the value of two fields at the same time (CITY = CIDADE, state = UF) but saw that was not possible, so I tried to do the update from both fields by ajax when the user selects the state and when finished entering the city. Like this:
<p:selectOneMenu>
<p:ajax event="change" process="@this"/>
</ p: selectOneMenu>

The method in the managed bean responsible to do the query will only make the query automatically if the city and state values ​​already filled in managed bean.

Comment: Sorry if it does not translate only three sentences of the image, but for me I spend all day trying to read this forum in another language translate three sentences or understand such an image is as easy as a pie. ¬¬'

Answer (score 0):

Other people had the same problem, and PrimeFaces addressed this:

[Issue 3593: Add process option to autocomplete](http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=3593)

```
Summary: Add process option to autocomplete
Labels: TargetVersion-3.2
[...]
We'll add process option which you can use to add other component
on page to decide what to process during search request.
[...]
Done, you now can do process="otherComponents" while entering data.
```

So you can now add attribute `process="otherComponent1 otherComponent2"` to the `<p:autocomplete>`. JSF should then set the values from those componentes in the backing bean on every autocomplete callback, just like during a regular submit, and your autocomplete callback can refer to the values.